# [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Can't establish connection to SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc

Very new to this so I do apologize.

My client sent me a .accdb file, .dsn, and .txt containing the username and password.

My assumption is that I need to start the ODBC Administer (64 bit), then add DSN file, and then input the username, password values when setting the connection up. However when I do that, my error says that the database does not exist OR my credentials are wrong.

Am I approaching the connection path completely wrong? Help steer me towards the right direction.

Comment: Is this .accbc file the new access file?https://www.lifewire.com/accdb-file-2619459

Answer (score 0):

The database does not exist error implies that the the server is not reachable based on the settings entered. This can happen if the database is behind a firewall and perhaps you need a VPN connect or the server name / database name are not correct. In the DSN, you should have the server name, IP address or domain name. You can try pinging the server name from a command prompt to see if you have connectivity to it. Is the database hosted on the clients network or hosted on the Internet i.e. godaddy.com or another web hosting provider?